# mini_magick wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) on .resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, minimagick

I'm not sure what's going on here.

Using MiniMagick 3.3, everything was working fine until I tried to resize.

This line is causing me to get a wrong number of arguments error:

```
image_file.resize "#{style.width}x#{style.height}"
```

Which seems like it should work fine according to the docs.

Here's the trace:

```
    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
RAILS_ROOT: /tmn_core_cms

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/mini_magick-3.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:323:in `combine_options'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/mini_magick-3.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:323:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/lib/imagemodule.rb:15:in `apply_styles'
/tmn_core_cms/lib/imagemodule.rb:11:in `apply_styles'
/tmn_core_cms/app/models/asset.rb:143:in `site_image_render'
/tmn_core_cms/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:66:in `update'
/tmn_core_cms/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:65:in `update'
```

image_file = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/i/Standard/#{baseimage.id}/original/#{baseimage.image_file_name}")

The image_file was returning the correct object ( I was testing everything as I added each step, it all worked up until I resized)

The top section says ArgumentError in ArticlesController#update

Here's the full trace:

```
ArgumentError in ArticlesController#update

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
RAILS_ROOT: /tmn_core_cms

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/mini_magick-3.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:323:in `combine_options'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/mini_magick-3.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:323:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/lib/imagemodule.rb:15:in `apply_styles'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:392:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `each'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:392:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:168:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.3.20/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/has_many_association.rb:19:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/lib/imagemodule.rb:11:in `apply_styles'
/tmn_core_cms/app/models/asset.rb:143:in `site_image_render'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2577:in `save_without_validation'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1090:in `save_without_dirty'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:356:in `save_has_one_association'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:182:in `autosave_associated_records_for_asset'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2577:in `save_without_validation'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1090:in `save_without_dirty'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2672:in `update_attributes_inside_transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2667:in `update_attributes'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
/tmn_core_cms/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:66:in `update'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:106:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:106:in `respond_to'
/tmn_core_cms/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:65:in `update'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-raw-upload-1.0.9/lib/rack/raw_upload.rb:17:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:67:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:38:in `run'
/tmn_core_cms/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
Request

Parameters:

{"article"=>{"asset_attributes"=>{"publish_date(1i)"=>"2011",
 "canonical"=>"",
 "name"=>"Test",
 "content_image_attributes"=>{"image_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"2"},
 "publish_date(2i)"=>"9",
 "by_line"=>"",
 "publish_date(3i)"=>"28",
 "guid"=>"",
 "display_authorbiography"=>"1",
 "content_section_attributes"=>{"id"=>"2",
 "primary_section"=>"1"},
 "publish_date(4i)"=>"06",
 "publish_date(5i)"=>"00",
 "id"=>"2",
 "public_keywords_string"=>"",
 "tagline"=>"",
 "keywords_string"=>"",
 "display_adsense"=>"1",
 "author_id"=>"1",
 "series_id"=>"",
 "partner_id"=>"",
 "short_desc"=>"Test"},
 "content_text"=>"<p>\r\n\tTest</p>\r\n"},
 "articlems2side__sx"=>"1",
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"R57YKHe3VD38JbpENgZf4ruSAffkyuVp18LY1qOfE/U=",
 "id"=>"2-test",
 "site"=>{"id"=>""},
 "secondary_site"=>{"id"=>""}}
Show session dump

Response

Headers:

{"Content-Type"=>"",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

Comment: What's `image_file` can you post the relevant code for that? Also, there should be more lines above that stacktrace. Can you post those as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the string interpolation with a value and test that, maybe something is going wrong there.

```
image_file.resize "250x250"
```

If that works then you need to look at your definition for `style` since it may not be defined properly or you may be calling a method by an incorrect name.

Edit 0:

Try opening a console for your application and running some example code for MiniMagick just so we can make sure its working:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("http://www.google.com/images/logos/logo.png")
image.resize "5x5"
```

If that works in your applications console then the problem exists somewhere besides the installation of the plugin.

Edit 1:

Ok well so its the installation method that's giving you trouble. Using bundler you can install dependencies inside the vendor directory which would give you all the same behaviour of having them installed on the system. Try running `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` See the [docs here](http://gembundler.com/bundle_install.html).

Comment: Devin, you're great thanks for your help.  Unfortunately changing to the string didn't help.  Maybe I should check my models and see if they have set up more "magic" in them.  That seems to be something that happens a lot here.

Comment: Take a look at edit 0, I just want to make sure the installation of the plugin is working.

Comment: Odd, it still fails.  I would have thought that would work.  Perhaps the method we're using to install the gem (since we can't "gem install" it) is causing the issue.  I haven't been able to find any other incidences of the issue through google.  There has to be something special about my case.

Comment: Yep then the issue exists with the installation method since you cant use it through a console. I found a cool solution though, see edit 1. Then you can remove your homebrew installation and use a supported method.

Comment: Got it working, forgot to bundle unpack the gem.  That was really silly of me.  Thanks for your help in tracking it down!